# Entity Framework CodeFirst Initial Migration of Existing Database

Tags: entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing database with data. I want to add code-first, non-automatic data migrations to the project.

My question is for the initial migration, should the initial migration be a snapshot of the current database schema or should it have empty Up() and Down() methods, essentially starting the migrations with the first schema change, when it occurs?

I can see the value in having the 1st migration being a snapshot of the existing schema. Just curious.

This?

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges
```

Or this?

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Add-Migration InitialMigration and Up() contains all the CreateTable etc calls required to set up the initial database. Seed() menthos in the Configuration class adds any data required.